# Can I have Gmail overwrite a known email with my contact info when a name is not supplied?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have to admit I was a little confused when [I asked this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22860/why-isnt-gmail-showing-the-name-instead-of-the-email-addresses-of-a-known-conta), as I thought that it was *my* Gmail where names and email addresses were connected.

But of course, it's not the local Gmail client that attaches a name to an email for display when receiving, it's whether or not the sender has a name attached to their email, as explained in [the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22889/13191).

Okay... but, can I set Gmail up in a way so that it will replace a known email address with the name I have for them in my contacts in situations when someone sends me an email with no name set? Or, even better, over rides their name with the one I have set in any case (since I think of them by the name I have set, not what they have set)?

This is standard practise when it comes to phone numbers - when someone calls my Android phone, I see the name that I have set in my contact list. Hopefully this could be done with emails as well.

Comment: Did you check the user card that shows up when hovering over the email address of a message to see what shows up?

Comment: hmm, so this does not happen in Gmail browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc) version? (Without the hover)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem with people that don't supply the correct info, or I know them by their nick name. I just overlooked an important email because the name displayed was `.` I've contacted them obviously and told them to fix it, but it would be nice if Gmail would do it for me.

Comment: @Larry: Nope, still no solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Currently still no, and probably never.** The name that is displayed when you receive an email is the name embedded into that emails `from:`header.  BUT there are two workarounds that I can think of, hopefully one will help you!

---

### Use Filters

One workaround solution is to [filter the email](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) address and apply a label to it. This can help if their name is causing any confusion (eg. I have 4 people called `Mike`)

*The Pros of using this is that it will sync across all your computers and devices.*

---

### Use a Script

There is a script called **[DisplayName gmail](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/83927)** that takes the contacts name (the one you have set in your contacts list) and displays that instead of their `from:` name.

You will need to install [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (Chrome) or [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) and then you can install the script **[DisplayName gmail](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/83927)** (tested and working with chrome).

*The cons of using a script is that its not going to work across multiple computers - you would need to install the script on each computer you use. And this also work on your phone.*

Comment: Damn... I'm sorry, I was going to award you the bounty for at least providing some helpful tips, but it expired and disappeared before I checked in on it. Nonetheless, your contributions are appreciated.

Comment: The above script has been removed or taken down, a backup is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20131106023031/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/83927

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you need to add every person to your contacts in Gmail as well as their additional email addresses. Because i just looked and tried. When I compose and start typing in a person's name, the drop down show the closest names as well as their email addresses.

Other than that you're talking about changing a user's (your contact's) settings which you can't do. You'll need to ask them to do that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is actually add them to your contacts list and go through filling out the info. Not go by what is automatically stored. Manually go through.